# Texto decoración CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy generando un menú simple con *CSS* y *HTML*, pero al querer eliminar los puntos de las listas hace un comportamiento raro.

```css
body{
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
ul >li 
{
 text-decoration:none;
 text-decoration-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>home</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Aclaración: Lo que me pareció realmente raro fue que al hacer otra cosa diferente, funcionara. Lo pondré aquí abajo y explicare.

El body es el mismo pero el otro cambia:

```css
ul > li:hover{

  color:white;
  background-color:black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>home</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
 <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Lo raro aquí es que sin el hover no funciona y con el hover, sí, aplica los cambios al pasar el mouse, sobre el `li` claro. ¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Como información extra estoy usando la versión más reciente de *Chrome* y *Visual Studio*, y ya lo probé con *Internet Explorer*, y solo elimina el `text-decoration` cuando cambio el `background` a negro y el color a blanco.

Comment: Aclaración el html es un simple ul con 4 li solo que no los represento correcta mente

Comment: dale en el boton ejecutar de mi respuesta. de esa manera lo probaras

Comment: elimina tus respuestas, si quieres comentar algo, dale en **añade un comentario**

Comment: @x-rw listo quisiera saber si sabes de algún curso en donde expliquen bien como crear código CSS correctamente ya que tengo nociones de como funciona pero siempre me ocurren errores que no se como solucionar y me gustaría aprender mas

Comment: a mi me ayudo http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp ahi esta los estandares de toda la web

Comment: @x-rw muchas gracias lo revisaré

Answer (score 3, accepted):

te falta

```
li{
  list-style:none
}
```

te dejo la solucion:

```css
body{

margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}
li{
  list-style:none
}
ul >li 
{

text-decoration:none;
text-decoration-style:none;
}


ul > li:hover{

color:white;
background-color:black;
text-decoration: none;
text-decoration-style:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>home</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
</ul>
```